# Develop third person view with x3dom?

Tags: webgl, x3dom

Someone can help me how i can develop an application on x3dom with a third person view?
The camera must follow together with a object and the object it's manipulated by left right keys.

cumps..

Answer (score 0):

to get a third person type view just place the Viewpoint in a transform grouping node adjust its rotation translation

```
<X3D><Scene>
<Transform translation="0 0 0">
<Viewpoint/>
<Shape><Box/></Shape>
</Transform>
</Scene></X3D>
```

please explain more for second part of question.